# Which alternative for type "object" could be in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

The rule [ban-types](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md) of newest [@typescript-eslint/ban-types](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) disallows `object` type as default.
I need to refactor my type analyzing functions according this rule.

I understand that TypeScript-ESLint is not source of truth, but wherever I follow to `ban-types` or violate it, I need to comprehend my decision.

```js
function isNonNullObject(potentialObject: unknown): potentialObject is object {
  return typeof potentialObject === "object" && potentialObject !== null;
}

function isNonEmptyObject(potentialObject: unknown): potentialObject is object {
  if (typeof potentialObject !== "object" || potentialObject === null) {
    return false;
  }
  return Object.entries(potentialObject as {[key: string]: unknown}).length > 0;
}


function isEmptyObject(potentialObject: unknown): potentialObject is object {
  if (typeof potentialObject !== "object" || potentialObject === null) {
    return false;
  }
  return Object.entries(potentialObject as {[key: string]: unknown}).length === 0;
}
```

The basic usage of this function external data analysis (from API or files):

```js
if (isNonNullObject(data)) {
  throw new Error("The data is invalid; object expected.");
}
```

Should I replace `object` to other type in this case, or exclusively here `object` is allowable?

### Usage example: data fetching

In real projects, data analyzing functionality is being wrapped to special utility, but it's the concept as below:

```js
type ValidResponseData = {
    products: Array<Products>;
    productsCount: number;
};


@Component
class ProductsListPage extends Vue {

  private products: Array<Products> = [];
  private productsCount: number = 0;

  private async created(): Promise<void> {

    try {

      // We must not trust to external data, so it's 'unknown'
      const responseData: unknown = await ProductFetchingAPI.fetchAllProducts();

      if (!isNonNullObject(responseData)) {
       throw new Error(
         `The response data data is invalid: non-null object expected, real type: ${typeof responseData},` +
         `, value: ${responseData}.`
       );
      }

      // Below checks are meaningless if "responseData" is not object.
      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(responseData, "products")) {
        throw new Error(
          "Expected that response data has 'products' property but it's missing".
        );
      }
      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(responseData, "productsCount")) {
         throw new Error(
           "Expected that response data has 'productsCount' property but it's missing".
         );
      }

      // 'products' and 'productsCount' analysis ....
      const validResponseData: ValidResponseData = responseData as ValidResponseData;

      this.products = validResponseData.products;
      this.productsCount = validResponseData.productsCount;

    } catch (error) {
      NotificationBarService.displayNotificationBar({
        type: NotificationBarService.NotificationsTypes.error,
        originalError: error,
        text: "Failed to fetch products."
      });           
    }
  }
}
```

### Usage example: data analyze from file

```js
const rawData: unknown = /* parse data from the file by appropriate library ... */;

if (!isNonNullObject(rawData)) {
 throw new Error(
   `The file content is invalid: non-null object expected, real type: ${typeof rawData},` +
     `, value: ${rawData}.`
 );
}

// Without isNonNullObject(rawData), we can not execute below loop
for (const value of Object.entires(rawData)) {
    // check each property
}
```

Comment: Would it be sufficient to check for particular types using generics of your functions and test wether what you're testing is of the type specified as the type parameter?

Comment: @Velulian, Thank you for the comment. I am sorry, would you please to append the example?

Comment: Aside: `isNonEmptyObject()` and `isEmptyObject()` are weird type guards.  When a type guard returns `false`, it tells the compiler that the object is *not* the type being guarded: `const empty = {}; if (isNonEmptyObject(empty)) throw new Error(); empty; // type is never?!` and `const nonEmpty = {a: ""}; if (isEmptyObject(nonEmpty)) throw new Error(); nonEmpty.a; // error!`.  That shows how a false result doesn't do what you want.  You might want [microsoft/TypeScript#15048](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048).

Comment: What type is `data`?  The reason ban-types doesn't like `object` is because if you have a value of type `object` it's hard to access properties.  But if `data` is a union type like `null | {a: string} | number` then I think you will not have this problem, since it will either be narrowed to `{a: string}` or `null | number`, neither of which are `object`.

Comment: @jcalz "What type is 'data'" - we don't know it in advance. It's a blackbox which must be analyzed. But when I using these functions, I am expecting that `data` is an object, otherwise the further program execution is meaningless.  "type is never?!" - these functions does not force to throw error. Instead, we can, for example, to display "invalid data" modal end finish the program execution without throwing error. `null | {a: string} | number` - please tell me why you mixed object with number.

Comment: Forget throwing an error.  If I call `isEmptyObject(data)` and it returns `false`, does that imply `data` is *not an `object`*?  No it does not.  Therefore the return type of `isEmptyObject` should not be `potentialObject is object`.  You should not use a user-defined type guard this way.  Please see microsoft/TypeScript#15048 for more info.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] where `data` is declared so I can understand the use case. We have to know *something* about `data` since you're calling it with TypeScript code, right?  Is it `unknown`?  Why are you calling `isNonEmptyObject(data)`?  Your example code says it's not valid (?!), but presumably you want to use a type guard function for some type narrowing purpose.  Otherwise you can just make `isNonEmptyObject()` return `boolean`.  What do you want to do with the `data` after it's been narrowed? Full example call site use cases will help inform the typing of the signature.

Comment: I added the usage example. "No it does not" - why? "We have to know something about data since you're calling it with TypeScript code, right?" - all we know is just which `data` is valid. **Real** `data` value could be anything. "Why are you calling isNonEmptyObject(data)" - it's a first step of data validation. If it's no object - the subsequent checking of properties is meaningless.

Comment: That usage example isn't taking any advantage of the user-defined type guard result; it never uses the fact that `responseData` is narrowed from `unknown` to `object`.  Can you explain why your functions are returning type predicates and not just `boolean`?  I have yet to see any code where you are using [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) for their intended purpose.  Try returning `boolean` instead of a type predicate and see if anything goes wrong anywhere.  If so, elaborate on that.

Comment: @jcalz, "Can you explain why your functions are returning type predicates and not just boolean" - to make TypeScript believe that it's object. After calling `isNonNullObject` we can pass the `data` as argument of `Object.values`(), for example.

Comment: Did you show that use case in your code example? did I miss it?

Comment: I will not take your time anymore. Thank you for the dialog. I understood that your position is "I don't see the necessity in predicates in you functions.". However, I'll start the bounty to hear the other opinions.

Comment: For `Object.entries()`, perhaps `{}` would suffice instead of `object`?  Alternatively, `object` is a perfectly reasonable type if you're just passing it to `Object.entries()` so you can decide to ignore/reconfigure ban-types.  I'd be happy to write that up, or you can wait for a bounty hunter.  I'm still quite dubious about `isEmptyObject()` returning `x is object` since there's no "empty object" type and `object` is a big mismatch... maybe `x is { [k: string]: never }` is closer?  `isNonEmptyObject()` is not as bad a mismatch but still, there's no type "non-empty object".

Comment: I'm happy to end the conversation if I've been annoying to you; don't feel the need to respond if you're looking to move past the part of your life where jcalz comments about stuff.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz "I've been annoying to you" - no way. You have show me that I don't understand enough what I doing, by other words - you teach me the vulnerability in my code. I thank you for it. Unfortunately, the time reserved for this problem solving is expired. For now, I'll disable the eslint for these functions, but if it's really the vicious path, I'll face with problems in the future and understand what I doing wrong. I can’t thank you enough for donation of your time. See you in other questions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than `isNonNullObject`, it should be sufficient to simply check:

```
// the `ban-types` rule should allow `Object` here because it's
// the value `Object`, not the type `Object`. Note the capital "O".
if (!(responseData instanceof Object)) {
  throw new Error(...);
}

// `responseData`'s type is now narrowed to `Object`, so you can now call `hasOwnProperty`
if (!responseData.hasOwnProperty("products")) {
 throw new Error(...);
}

...
```

This article also might serve as a nice refresher:
https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-object-type-in-typescript

Answer (score 1):

As for the replacement type for object: `Record<string, unknown>` is a good start - basically it is saying the data is an object with string properties of unknown values.

As for the type checks - I recently made a TypeScript transformer that can create type guards from your types automatically, it is called `ts-type-checked` and it is [available on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-type-checked), type-check it out! :D

With `ts-type-checked` you no longer need to manually check whether an `unknown` object matches a certain type (or interface), you can just write:

```js
import { isA } from 'ts-type-checked';

// ...

if (isA<ValidResponseData>(value) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't returning a `boolean` enough for your case?

```
function isNonNullObject(potentialObject: unknown): boolean {
  return typeof potentialObject === "object" && potentialObject !== null;
}

function isNonEmptyObject(potentialObject: unknown): boolean {
  if (typeof potentialObject !== "object" || potentialObject === null) {
    return false;
  }
  return Object.entries(potentialObject as {[key: string]: unknown}).length > 0;
}

function isEmptyObject(potentialObject: unknown): boolean {
  if (typeof potentialObject !== "object" || potentialObject === null) {
    return false;
  }
  return Object.entries(potentialObject as {[key: string]: unknown}).length === 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, the casting required, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood.

Comment: I mean if we replace `: potentialObject is object` to `: boolean`, casting `as {[key: string]: unknown}` will required to use `Object.entries`.

Comment: Probaly it depends on some ts options. With my tsconfig.json I don't need to change nothing else. Anyway isn't that cast already done?

Comment: Sorry @GurebuBokofu , I didn't understood if it is working for you as well, or you are experiencing some other problem

Comment: It works for me well. I am using this function for the year in real project. All I need that is to decide, should I disable TypeScript/ESLint for these function or rewrite them.